QGIS Server - error in insert transaction (size too large)
I'm using QGIS Server for my application.
I do an insertion in a QGIS project through the app.
The transaction XML body contains a property that is an image in base64 format.
I receive an internal server error "size too large" when the image is over 7kb.
I modified these in the Apache files.
'''''''''httpd_qgis.conf''''''''''''
<Directory "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/">
    SetHandler fcgid-script
    AllowOverride None
    Options ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    LimitRequestBody 5242880
    LimitXMLRequestBody 5242880
</Directory>

''''''''httpd.conf''''''''''
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
FcgidMaxRequestLen 13550000
</IfModule>

Nevertheless, it is still not working.
Any idea?
